# Capture keyboard input in a persistent program

Tags: assembly, nasm, dos, x86-16, interrupt-handling

I am trying to create a simple "cheating" program for old dos games that would work by loading itself into memory, then intercept keyboard input and do something when a certain key is pressed.

So I capture the input by

```
cli                        
mov ax, [es:9*4+2]     
mov [origseg], ax
mov ax, [es:9*4]
mov [origint], ax

mov     word [es:9*4], kbhandler
mov     [es:9*4+2],cs
sti
```

and then, at the end of kbhandler, I pass control to the original handler by

```
push word [origseg]
push word [origint]
retf
```

According to the debugger, this works, however eventually it crashes on 
"illegal unhandled interrupt called 0" (in dosbox). I have already reduced my own handler to contain nothing except the code above and the issue persists.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try putting `origseg/int` in the code segment of your ISR and using `CS`. When your code is executed you don't know what value `DS` has. I usually implemented the call to the original ISR with a far jump, to not even touch the stack.

Comment: BTW, you can far jump more easily with `jmp far dword [seg_and_pointer]` (or whatever the syntax is for a far `jmp` with a `m16:16` destination.  Your problem might be that you're modifying AX asynchronously, breaking whatever code is running when the interrupt fires.

Comment: Thank you. Of course my DS/CS mismatch was the problem. I had DS=CS in the main code, but of course that was no longer the case in the interrupt code.